# When would I need to implement operator [] ?

Tags: c++, class, templates

given the following template function :

```
template <class T>
void DoSomething(T &obj1, T &obj2)
{
      if(obj1 > obj2)
        cout<<"obj1 bigger: "<<obj1;
      else if(obj1 == obj2)
        cout<<"equal";
      else cout<<"obj2 bigger: "<<obj2;

      T tmp(3);
      T array[2];
      array[0]=obj1;
      array[1]=obj2;
}
```

I need to define a class called MyClass (declarations only , i.e. just the .h file) , that would be able to work with that template function .
I defined the next declarations :

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();    // default ctor
    MyClass(int x);  // for ctor with one argument
    bool operator ==(const MyClass& myclass) const;
    bool operator >(const MyClass& myclass) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,const MyClass& myclass);  // output operator

};
```

What I don't understand is why there is no need to define operator [] for the lines:

```
array[0]=obj1; array[1]=obj2;
```

? When would I need to define operator []? 
thanks ,Ron

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared an array for your type:

```
T array[2];
```

But your are talking about implementing operator[] for `T`, which is totally different concept.

If you need

```
T t;
t[1] = blah
```

Then you need to implement operator[]

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
T array[2];
```

Isn't a T object, its an array of T. So

```
array[0];
```

Is indexing an array, not one of your objects, therefore you don't need an operator[].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you call `DoSomething` with a couple of `MyClass` objects, you have declared `array` to be a normal array of `MyClass` objects.  You did not need a `[]` operator for `MyClass` because `array` is not an instance of `MyClass`; it is just an array.

You will want to overload the `[]` operator in your own classes when it makes sense to, or is convenient.  A good example is a collection (such as a map).  Another example is a custom string class, where you might want to index by a regex object to find matches for your pattern inside your string.

Answer (score 0):

If your class was an implementation of a dynamic array, for example, you would want to access the (single) object *as though* it was an array - you this by overloading the [] operator.